# Why does this shuffle function only work with 4+ items? JsFiddle included

Tags: javascript, jquery, shuffle

I have the following code, which shuffles a set of items in the row of a table. However, the shuffle function only works when there are 4+ items:

```js
var parent = $("#parent");


function shuffleRows(parent) {
  var rows = parent.children().children(".shuffledtd1");
  for (var i = rows.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = rows[i];
    rows.eq(i - 1).after(rows[j]);
    rows.eq(j - 1).after(temp);
  }
}

shuffleRows(parent);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="parent">

    <tr id="node2" class="shufflerow">
      <td class="shuffledtd shuffledtd1">AA</td>
      <td class="shuffledtd shuffledtd1">BB</td>

      <!-- IF I DELETE THIS AND THE FOLLOWING ROW, THE PRIOR 2 ROWS NO LONGER SHUFFLE -->
      <td class="shuffledtd shuffledtd1">CC</td>
      <td class="shuffledtd shuffledtd1">DD</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Full Code: http://jsfiddle.net/d8rkgx0z/

I think it has something to do with this portion of the code:

```
    rows.eq(i - 1).after(rows[j]);
    rows.eq(j - 1).after(temp);
```

but, unfortunately, my skill set simply isn't robust enough to isolate and correct the issue without hours of trial and error.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Why are you using `.children().children()`? Can't you just pass the `tr` element directly and use one `children` call?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I probably could but that portion of the code works fine. (At least, I'm fairly certain that `.children().children()` isn't causing the issue.) Do you know why the shuffle function only works with 4+ items?

Comment: Btw, do you mean to shuffle rows or cells? Your function name says the former where your function combined with your HTML would do the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `children` twice, just pass in the direct parent of the cells. Also, shuffling the children is a lot easier using `jQuery#sort`:

```
var parent = $("#node2");                                        // parent should be the tr element not the tbody which is in fact a grandparent not a parent

function shuffleChildren(parent) {
  parent.children()                                              // get the children of the parent element
        .sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; })        // sort them randomly (shuffling)
        .appendTo(parent);                                       // add them back to parent so that the shuffling takes effect
}

shuffleChildren(parent);
```

**Example:**

```js
var parent = $("#node2");                                        // parent should be the tr element not the tbody which is in fact a grandparent not a parent

function shuffleChildren(parent) {
  parent.children()                                              // get the children of the parent element
        .sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; })        // sort them randomly (shuffling)
        .appendTo(parent);                                       // add them back to parent so that the shuffling takes effect
}

shuffleChildren(parent);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="parent">
    <tr id="node2" class="shufflerow">
      <td class="shuffledtd shuffledtd1">AA</td>
      <td class="shuffledtd shuffledtd1">BB</td>
      <td class="shuffledtd shuffledtd1">CC</td>
      <td class="shuffledtd shuffledtd1">DD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note:** If you want to do this to all rows, then just use `jQuery#each`:

```
$("#parent tr").each(function() {                                // get all tr inside #parent
    shuffleChildren($(this));                                    // shuffle their children
});
```

BTW, what you're shuffling are cells not rows.

Comment: Ahh, that is, indeed, a more streamlined way to do it - and it fixes the issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BlahBlahBloo You're welcome! BTW to understand why your code doesn't work just use paper and pen. I was trying to find a way to add the explanation to the answer but couldn't. Just draw 3 boxes and apply your algorithm to them and you'll get what's wrong with it.

Comment: Will do! Thanks, again, for your time.

Answer (score 1):

ibrahim mahrir's answer is the more elegant way to do what you're trying to do, but in the interest of helping you understand why your solution wasn't working I'm posting this as well.

**The Problem:**

The problem you were seeing is because when i = 0, when you do (i - 1) you get negative one, which is not a valid index in your table.

> rows.eq(i - 1).after(rows[j]);

**The way to make your solution work:**

Below is how you could have solved that issue with your existing code:

```js
function shuffleRows(parent) {
    var rows = parent.children().children(".shuffledtd1");
    // Changed to i >= 0.
    for (var i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = rows[i];
        // Changed to just i, instead if i-1.
        rows.eq(i).after(rows[j]);
        rows.eq(j - 1).after(temp);
    }
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
 shuffleRows($("#parent"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tbody id="parent">

        <tr id="node2" class="shufflerow">
            <td class="shuffledtd shuffledtd1">AA</td>
            <td class="shuffledtd shuffledtd1">BB</td>
            <td class="shuffledtd shuffledtd1">CC</td>

        </tr>
  
    </tbody>
</table>
<button>Shuffle</button>
```

This snippet just made two small changes, which I noted in the code, to avoid the negative index problem you had.

Again, there are much more elegant ways to approach this task, but I always get a lot out of understand why something doesn't work, so I wanted you to have an explanation.

Comment: Wow, people on this site are helpful! This is great. Thanks

Comment: Upvoted for actually debugging it :) Most people (like me) simply dismiss the entire script when we have a much easier solution in mind

Answer (score 0):

Your script can be simplified by great lengths, especially using proper selectors and a random sorter (Covered both cases of sorting `td` within a `tr` - or `tr` within a `tbody`:

```js
const randomSorter = () => 0.5 - Math.random();

$('.shufflecells tr').each(function() {
  $(this).html($('td', this).sort(randomSorter));
});

$('.shufflerows').each(function() {
  $(this).html($('tr', this).sort(randomSorter));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody class="shufflecells">
    <tr>
      <td>AA</td>
      <td>BB</td>
      <td>CC</td>
      <td>DD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <tbody class="shufflecells">
    <tr>
      <td>AA</td>
      <td>BB</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <tbody class="shufflerows">
    <tr>
      <td>AA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I'll take your suggestions.